# Find all eigenvalues of a matrix that holds $A = A^{5}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find all eigenvalues of a matrix that holds $A = A^{5}$. I have no idea where to start. Any directions please?

Comment: The fileld is $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$?

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial such that $P(A)=0$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ must be roots of $P$.

Comment: the field is $c$

Comment: It's not possible to find the eigenvalues  of  $A$ exactly, given just that $A^5=A$. _Exactly_ what does the question ask you to do?

Comment: You can't really find *all* the eigenvalues; what you can prove is, at most, that the eigenvalues live in the set of roots of $\lambda^5=\lambda$.  For instance, the zero matrix satisfies the condition, but its only eigenvalue is $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ will solve the equation $\lambda^5=\lambda$ because
$$0=(A^{5}-A)v=(\lambda^5-\lambda)v$$
where $v$ is an eigenvector with respect to $\lambda$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$
\lambda^5-\lambda=0 \quad \iff \quad \lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2+1)=0
$$